# Two lightboxes on same page overlaps

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I'm using a customized lightbox for showing images on my webpage.

When I use the same lightbox twice on the same page. some sort of mistake happens.

I've divided each lightbox by placing the content in two seperate divs and adding the script twice referencing each lightbox and thereby seperating them.

When I reload the page I get numerous different mistakes.

Have a look.

```js
           

        <!--Lightbox script-->
        
        <script>
        function openModal() {
          document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "block";
        }
        
        function closeModal() {
          document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "none";
        }
        
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        
        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
        
        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        
        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
          var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
          captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
        }
        </script>
    

         <!--Lightbox script-->
        
        <script>
        function openModal() {
          document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "block";
        }
        
        function closeModal() {
          document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";
        }
        
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        
        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
        
        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        
        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
          var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
          if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
          dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
          captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
        }
        </script>
```

```css
.containercontent1

{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:750px;
 }

.containercontent2

{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:750px;
 }

/* Lightbox css */

.column1 {
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:5px;
float:left;
width:30%; }

.column1:hover {
cursor:pointer; }

.modal1 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal2 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:12;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width:900px; 
  
  
}
  
/* lightbox buttons*/
 
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 4);
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/*lightbox img*/
img{
margin-bottom: -4px;}
```

```html
  <div class="containercontent1">


        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" class="column1" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" class="column1" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

        </div>

            <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

              <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>


                                <div class="modal-content">

                                            <div class="mySlides">
                                              <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
                                              <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="mySlides">
                                              <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
                                              <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>




                                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


                                    </div>  

            </div>








    <div class="containercontent2">



                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" class="column1" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">


                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" class="column1" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">


                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" class="column1" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">              

    </div>


          <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

              <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>


                                <div class="modal-content">

                                            <div class="mySlides">
                                              <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                                              <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="mySlides">
                                              <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                                              <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="mySlides">
                                              <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                                              <img src="" style="width:100%">
                                            </div>



                                                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                                                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


                                    </div>        
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you define functions with the same name two times.
The two -tags are not seperated in scope so if you define a function with the same name the latest defined one will always win.

So choose different names for your functions or write generic function which will check for which trigger was clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Don't I seperate the function by referencing them to different div's with different id's? 

First id named mymodal1 second called mymodal2

Comment: where do I name my functions if not with id tag?

Comment: actually you have e.g. the js "openModal" two times... so that the second definition will overwrite the first one, so its not about your id-selector but about the function itselfe. If you now execute "openModal" it will always to what is defined in the second one.
So one way arround is renaming the second one e.g. openModal2 better would be to make use of "this" or the passed event in the openModal and identify which element was clicked and open the corresponding Modal (without having it hardcoded in the function)

Comment: if you add an jsfiddle i'll look into it again and probably show you an possible solution, if you like